# How to insert a lot of similar data in mysql using PHP PDO Prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I am inserting data from JSON file using A API.

Now, the JSON file will send `genres`. Now, some JSON file will send 2 genres values, some JSON fie will send 100 values.

So, I don't know, how insert them.

See this code, this is a short version of my code. Currently, I have `genres1` to `genres100` numbers for each title in my original file. But here, i only shown `genres1` to `genres5`, for the sake of simplicity.

So, as you can see, the code is very long, if i insert upto 100 genres value. How to make it short? Using Forloop or something?

```
   <?php

    $requestsDone = 1;
    $maxRequests = 15;

    while ($requestsDone <= $maxRequests) {
    include 'logo/connectdb.php';

    $requestsDone++;

        $response = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/".($requestsDone-1)."?api_key=522cexxxxxxe0c834a");
        if ($response != FALSE) {
            $response = json_decode($response, true);
        }

    $firstname = "";
    $lastname = "";


    try {


        // prepare sql and bind parameters
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE (title, genres1,genres2,genres3,genres4,genres5) 
        VALUES (:title, :genres)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
        $stmt->bindParam(':genres1', $genres1);
        $stmt->bindParam(':genres2', $genres2);
        $stmt->bindParam(':genres3', $genres3);
        $stmt->bindParam(':genres4', $genres4);
        $stmt->bindParam(':genres5', $genres5);

        // insert a row
        $title = $response["title"];
    if ( isset($response["genres"][0]["name"]) != ""        )
        $genres1 = $response["genres"][0]["name"];
    if ( isset($response["genres"][1]["name"]) != ""        )
        $genres2 = "".$response["genres"][1]["name"]."";
    if ( isset($response["genres"][2]["name"]) != ""        )
        $genres3 = "".$response["genres"][2]["name"]."";
    if ( isset($response["genres"][3]["name"]) != ""        )
        $genres4 = "".$response["genres"][3]["name"]."";
    if ( isset($response["genres"][4]["name"]) != ""        )
        $genres5 = "".$response["genres"][4]["name"]."";

        $stmt->execute();

        echo "New records created successfully";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you seriously have 100 columns to store the same thing in a table?

Comment: yes @apokryfos , what's wrong?

Comment: That's bad database design. You need a **one-to-many relationship** instead. In a simplified example you'd have a table with `id`,`title` and another table with `other_table_id`,`genre` and have one entry in the 2nd table for each genre that correspond to an entry in the first table. That way you'd loop through an insert.

Comment: @apokryfos It's the same thing, i guess. Then i need to put 100 columns in table 2 right?

I am not expert at MySQL, may be it is complicated for u, but i find it easy than one to many thing

Comment: no. just 2 columns in table 2, but you'll have between 0 and 100 rows in table 2 for each row in table 1

Comment: Oh, So I need to just google "One to many relationship in PHPMyAdmin" right? 

Thanks :)

Comment: Do that, I'll try to provide a practical example as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using 2 tables instead of 1.

Assume tables (Note: genre_id or the autoincremented id do not go in this table)

```
movie
-----
tmdb_id | movie_title | budget


genre
-----------
genre_id (autoincrement primary key) | movie_id(foreign key) | genre_title
```

Your PHP would look like:

```
<?php

$requestsDone = 1;
$maxRequests = 15;

while ($requestsDone <= $maxRequests) {
include 'logo/connectdb.php';

$requestsDone++;

    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/".($requestsDone-1)."?api_key=522cexxxxxxe0c834a");
    if ($response != FALSE) {
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
    }

$firstname = "";
$lastname = "";


try {
    $title = $response["title"];
    $tmdb_id = $response["tbdb_id"]; //Or the correct name
    $budget = $response["budget"];
    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO movie (tmdb_id,movie_title,budget) 
    VALUES (:tmdbid,:title,:budget)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':tmdbid', $title,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':budget', $title,PDO::PARAM_INT);

    // insert a row

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO genre (movie_id,genre_title) VALUES (:genrefk,:title)");
    $genre = "";
    $stmt->bindParam(':genrefk', $tmdb_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $genre);
    if (isset($response["genres"]) && is_array($response["genres"])) {
         foreach ($response["genres"] as $genreObject) {
             $genre = $genreObject["name"]; 
             $stmt->execute(); 
         }
     }

    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
}
?>
```

What this does is:

1. Inserts the movie information
2. Inserts between 0 to N movie genres which are in the result. Each genre is a new insert in another table.

To get all genres associated with a movie you'd do something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM movie JOIN movie_genre ON movie_genre.movie_id=movie.id;
```

Note: I've assumed that you'd use an automatically incrementing identifier for this but you can realistically use an identifier that is provided by the API instead. In that case you just need to change the "thisId" and the first insert accordingly.

Comment: Hey bro, thanks a lot but   See this screenshot of MySQL: http://prntscr.com/fo7ss8

It only insert 1st genres. But a movie may have multiple genres like: Drama, Action

Comment: You don't seem to have a foreign key referencing movies in that table. Also in that case the **pair** `movie_id,genre` should be unique but not each one individually.

Comment: I do not understand. I watched some youtube videos. I connected genres_id with tmdb_id from other table. If i delete one row in tmdb_movies table, it gets deleted in genres_id. 

http://prntscr.com/fo7xbs ss of other table

Comment: Is there a primary key in the genres table? Check the table structure in phpMyAdmin the primary key would get highlighted if there is one. There shouldn't be one, it should either be a pair or none.

Comment: Btw, In your code, both time you are telling to insert data into movie table, not movie_genres table, is it like that or i change the last one to insert into movie_genres?

Comment: is `genres_fk` meant to be the `movie_id` reference? Yes, second insert is for the `movie_genres` table.

Comment: Genres_fk = foreign key, this is my relationship http://prntscr.com/fo87wq

Comment: @JohnDoo updated. Check my suggested changes for the movie table. You don't need to autoincremented id if you're using the remote resource id, in addition the genre_id does not go on the movie table.

Comment: tmdb_movies table structure = http://prntscr.com/fo8p4a

tmdb_movies data = http://prntscr.com/fo8pd3

genres table structure = http://prntscr.com/fo8pm7

genres table data = http://prntscr.com/fo8ptk

forign key relationship  = http://prntscr.com/fo8q3x

And from my heart "Thanks a lot"

Comment: The foreign key still looks like it's null. Double check the insert statements, make sure you're using the correct field names (and that there's no errors).

Comment: I changed genres_fk name to movie_id... In your code, you missed what value should i insert to genres_fk??? Thanks

Comment: `$tmdb_id` is that that column is refering to so that should be the value to be inserted.

Comment: oh, i made few changes to your code. Not sure, if they are right. Here it is https://pastebin.com/E1Jk7QaC

Comment: @JohnDoo looks like it.

Comment: How do i echo them? See this SS, If one movie have 2 genres, then the movie name repeats. http://prntscr.com/fo8ycx

this is my current code 

` for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){
   
   
   echo 'title= '.$result[$x]["movie_title"].' genres='.$result[$x]["genres_title"].' <br/>  '; 
   
  }`

Comment: Simple thing to do would be `SELECT movie.*, GROUP_CONCAT(genres_title) as genres_title FROM movie JOIN genres ON movie.tmdb_id=genres.movie_id GROUP BY movie.tmdb_id;` then it should work the way you're currently iterating. There's more things to it when it comes to relational data and that really is a very broad topic. Reading about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is usually good to get an idea on why some things are done the way they are.

Comment: Last thing, i am getting this error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'KC_movies.tmdb_movies.movie_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in `

Comment: Code: `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.*, GROUP_CONCAT(genres_title) as genres_title 
FROM tmdb_movies JOIN genres ON tmdb_movies.tmdb_id=genres.movie_id GROUP BY tmdb_movies.tmdb_id  ");`

Comment: `GROUP BY tmdb_movies.move_id, tmdb_movies.tmdb_id, tmdb_movies.movie_title, tmdb_movies.budget` would work. The new (5.7+) MySQL grouping rules are stricter than the older ones so all columns except the functions need to be mentioned in the group by.

Comment: Bro can u answer this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793318/how-to-filter-data-in-mysql-one-to-many-relationship-using-php/44794194