# How to filter data in MySQL (One to many relationship) using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

> What I  Want To Do

The user will send a value using `GET` and I will store the value in a variable named `$category1`. Now all the rows which contain the value of `$category1` will display. This is like a search system.

> This is my code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS genres

FROM tmdb_movies

JOIN genres ON genres.genres_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

WHERE EXISTS (SELECT genres.genres_name FROM genres WHERE genres.genres_name = '$category1');

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title");
```

Error: Because of WHERE Exist line (IDK, if I should use it or no)

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'DataBaseName.tmdb_movies.movie_title'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Let me explain my Table Structure now

I have two tables

1. `tmdb_movies` (it store movie title and tmdb_id)
2. `genres` (It stores genres, which is connected via tmdb_id)

The example of tables.

> `tmdb_movies` table

```
tmdb_id     movie_title
1           The_Dark_Night
2           Logan
3           IronMan
```

> `genres` table

```
tmdb_id       genres
 1            Action
 1            Crime
 1            Drama
 2            Action
 2            Drama
 3            Action
 3            Comedy
```

Answer (score 0):

In 5.7 the sqlmode is set by default to:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,
 NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,
 STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,
 NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

To remove the clause **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** you can do this:

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

This supposed you need to make that GROUP BY with non aggregated columns.

otherwise i tested your code locally it working perfectly fine.
[image]

Comment: Where should i put this code `SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
` ??

Comment: you can change your db setting with above command. for more ref.. check   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting

Comment: is it reverseable? Just in case

Comment: Where can i change the settings? I cannot find it. I did this `Go to phpmyadmin > open my database > SQL tab> paste the code` but same error

Comment: Go to phpmyadmin > open my database > SQL tab> write sql  "SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));SELECT @@sql_mode;"

Comment: select @@sql_mode  will show u your current db setting

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'KC_movies.tmdb_movies.movie_title'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by `

Comment: I did what u said, what's wrong? I copied and pasted it `SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));SELECT @@sql_mode;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147803/discussion-between-mausumi-and-john-doo).